# Criar txt com nome da Default printer em VBS

Tags: script, vbs

Bom dia, estou com o seguinte script.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strValue = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device"
strPrinter = oShell.RegRead(strValue)
strPrinter = Split(strPrinter, ",")(0)
```

Gostaria de criar um arquivo `.txt` com o nome da variável `strPrinter`.
Utilizo `BGinfo` para informar qual a impressora padrão porém ela traz `server\modelo\ip`.

Seria interessante trazer apenas o nome da impressora, para isso vou gerar um arquivo txt e utilizar o nome do arquivo como referencia para a informação da impressora.

Como criar um arquivo txt com o nome da variável?
Posso também resolver colocando a informação dentro do arquivo txt. 
Criando por exemplo um arquivo chamado "Printer.txt"

Comment: FileSystemObject https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.84).aspx Qual é a dificuldade em concreto?

Comment: Exemplo: No meu codigo a variavel strPrinter = \\HPPPS001\BrotherXXXX.
Quero que isso seja colocado dentro de um arquivo .txt "que será criado" a partir do script. 
Seria inserir essa informação em um .txt criado pelo vbs. 

O que vou fazer com isso?

Utilizo bginfo para informar usuario atual, nome da máquina, IP e etc..
Estou incluindo a impressora padrão para que o usuário veja...
Consigo trazer direto do registro, mas ele traz assim: "\\HPPPS001\BrotherXXXX, Brother 2270, 192.168.0.X"

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido!
Segue solução:

```
Dim fso, MyFile, printer
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\printer.txt", True)
MyFile.WriteLine(strPrinter)
MyFile.Close
```